# The reputation tab in Network Profile is showing incorrect graphs

Tags: bug, reputation, network-profile

The [Reputation tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/15799588/ak?tab=reputation) in my Network Profile is showing that I have a rep. of 3,728 in **Economics Meta Stack Exchange**. That's my rep. in **Puzzling Stack Exchange** and moreover I don't have an account in Economics Stack Exchange.  It's also not showing the graphs of sites where I have more than 200 rep.

[image]

I tried visiting some others' Reputation tabs too. For some it's consistent and for others it's again showing inconsistent data.

For example, **José Carlos Santos** doesn't have an **Internet of Things** account but his [Reputation tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/10895929/jos%c3%a9-carlos-santos?tab=reputation) showing he has a rep. of 3,972 in IOT Meta SE.  This is his rep. in **History of Science and Mathematics**

[image]